# Blazor NavMenu displaying API data. Do i need a whole new NavMenu or "toggle" between NavLinks?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Displaying Chapters and Lessons in NavMenu on Course Page in Blazor Server

I am working on a Course application with chapters and lessons using Blazor Server. I am using a Web API project to display my courses, chapters, and lessons. However, I would like to see my chapters and lessons in my NavMenu when I am on a certain course page. How can I achieve this?

I have a component which i try to load into my navmenu. I think this doesn't work becuase the NavMenu doesn't get initialized again  when i change pages.

```
@using EBu.KnowledgeAcademyApp.Web.Pages

<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">KnowledgeAcademy</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
      
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="courses" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>Courses
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        @*Component to add Chapters and lessons navlinks*@
        <CourseNavBar></CourseNavBar>
    </nav>
</div>

@code {



    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

The component:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@if (Course != null && (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("/chaptersandlessons") || NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("/lessonvideoplayer")))
{
    @foreach (var chapter in Course.Chapters)
    {
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink href="@($"/chapters/{chapter.ChapterId}")" ActiveClass="active-link" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                @chapter.Title
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        @foreach (var lesson in chapter.Lessons)
        {
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink href="@($"/lessons/{lesson.LessonId}")" ActiveClass="active-link" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                    @lesson.Title
                </NavLink>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
}

@code {
    [Parameter] // This attribute indicates that this property can receive a value from the component's parent
    public int CourseId { get; set; } // This property stores the courseId parameter from the route

    public Course Course { get; set; }


    // This property stores the course object that will be fetched from the API

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        @if (Course != null && (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("/chaptersandlessons") || NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("/lessonvideoplayer")))
        {
            Course = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Course>($"https://localhost:7160/api/Courses/{CourseId}");
        }
    }

}
```

The Page where the new nav links should be added

```
@page "/chaptersandlessons/{courseId:int}"


@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager


<div class="container-fluid ps-5">

    <div class="row  pt-5">
        
        @if (Course == null)
        {
            <p>Loading...</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="col pb-5">
                <h3>@Course?.Title</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row bg-li align-items-center px-5">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="/Images/course.png" class="card-img-top " alt="...">

                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <h5>[Chapter 1] last followed lesson</h5>
                    <a href="lesson" class="btn btn-primary">Youtube lesson</a>
                    <a href="lessonvideoplayer" class="btn btn-primary">MP4 Lesson</a>
                </div>

                <div class="row pt-5">
                    <div class="col-9">
                        @foreach (var chapter in Course.Chapters)
                        {
                            <div class="card my-3">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">@chapter.Title</h5>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                    @foreach (var lesson in chapter.Lessons)
                                    {
                                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                            <div>@lesson.Title</div>
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="@($"/lessonvideoplayer/{lesson.LessonId}")" class="btn btn-primary">MP4 Lesson</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                    @if (chapter.Lessons == null || chapter.Lessons.Count == 0)
                                    {
                                        <li class="list-group-item text-muted">No lessons found.</li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        }
                        @if (Course.Chapters == null || Course.Chapters.Count == 0)
                        {
                            <p>No chapters found.</p>
                        }
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
</div>


@code {

    [Parameter] // This attribute indicates that this property can receive a value from the component's parent

    public int CourseId { get; set; } // This property stores the courseId parameter from the route

    public Course Course { get; set; } // This property stores the course object that will be fetched from the API

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    { 
        Course = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Course>($"https://localhost:7160/api/Courses/{CourseId}");
    }
}
```

I realize that this is not the "Blazor" way to do it and i would like to implement the "Blazor" way of doing this.

I think this is the solution im looking for but im not sure how to implement it:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handle-cancellations-in-onnavigateasync

Current outcome:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtIjt.png)

Expected/wanted outcome:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5ORO.png)